# Can anyone tell me how to avoid on click error in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, hyperlink, buttonclick

> Expected `onclick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of
> `string` type.
> getListener@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18256:15
> accumulateSinglePhaseListeners@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22846:39

```
<button onClick={Window.href='https://github.com/'} className="btn btn-github" >
```

I am using react js. During on click event shows the above error tell me how I can solve it I will be very glad?
My on click event is not working while using react.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```js
onClick={() => {window.href='https://github.com/'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Expected onclick listener to be a function, instead got a value of string type.

As the error states, the `onClick` handler expects a **function**, not a **string**. Just wrap your sample with a function call.

```
onClick={() => {
   Window.href = 'https://github.com/';
}}
```